# MongoDB V2 C# get file name

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

```
GridFSFileInfo fileInfo;
var options = new GridFSFindOptions
{
    Limit = 1
};
FilterDefinition<GridFSFileInfo> filterDefinition = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter
    .Where(ee => ee.Id.Equals(new ObjectId(fileId)));
using (var cursor = _mongoDbHelper.Bucket.Find(filterDefinition, options))
{
    fileInfo = cursor.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
}             
byte[] file = _mongoDbHelper.Bucket.DownloadAsBytes(new ObjectId(fileId));
UploadedFile uploadedFile = new UploadedFile(fileInfo.Filename, file);                  
return uploadedFile;
```

I am using mongoDB v2 in c# and I want to downaload byte[] and in addition get the file name by giving fileId but in line:

```
_mongoDbHelper.Bucket.Find(filterDefinition, options)
```

its throw me an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException

and the message is:

> {document}.Id is not supported.

but GridFSFileInfo has an property name ID.
How can i find the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found different answer to that problem:

```
var stream = _mongoDbHelper.Bucket.OpenDownloadStream(new ObjectId(fileId));
            var fileName = stream?.FileInfo.Filename;
```